# VBA, error while using lookup

Tags: vba, excel

I am having two Sheets BW and PSW.

With the BW the data is starting from row 4. the above 3 rows are merged and I have some command Buttons there. the sheet PSW starts from 1st row.

I am looking for the ID in sheet1,which starts from L5 and when the Id matches in sheet2, it pulls the date from sheet2 to sheet1. 
I am using the below code. The code, is not executing any Output. Could anyone tell where I am making mistake.

I suppose,in the below line,  the range starts from A and since my data starts from row5, it does not Count. if this is the case, then how i should Change the range. I had this code running, if my data starts with row1 without any command buttons.

> totalrows = Sheets("BW").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

```
Sub lookupePSR()
Dim totalrows As Long, totalrowsSht2 As Long
totalrows = Sheets("PSW").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
totalrowsSht2 = Sheets("PSW").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("PSW").Range("AA5:AA" & totalrows).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("PSW").Range("L5:L" & totalrowsSht2), Sheets("PSW").Range("$A:$L"), 7, 0), "")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to put **formulas** in the cells, or the **results** of formulas in the cells ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent   result of the formula in cells

Comment: `Sheets("PSW").Range("AA5:AA" & totalrows).Formula = "PUT ACTUAL FORMULA HERE"` Put the formula in the worksheet and then put it in the code that I gave. Replace all `"`, if any, with `""`

Comment: @SiddharthRout ya , will try and let you know

Comment: Remember to put the formula in `AA5` and then use that. If it doesn't work then post the formula that you manually put in `AA5`

Comment: ya, i will do it

Comment: @SiddharthRout =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L5;PSW!$A:$L;7;0);"") i used the same formula, it is also not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148139/discussion-between-mikz-and-siddharth-rout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, put the actual formula into the worksheet; optionally revert to the values returned by the formulas.

```
with Sheets("PSW").Range("AA5:AA" & totalrows)
    .Formula = "=iferror(vlookup(l5, $a:$g, 7, false), text(,))"
    'optionally revert the formulas' returned values to values in cells
    .value = .value
end with
```

The `TEXT(,)` is the same as `""`; i.e. a zero-length string. I use this because you have to double-up double-quotes (e.g. `""` becomes `""""`) when used in a quoted string like the formula above and that confuses matters.

I've cut your lookup range down to A:G since you are only looking for the seventh column in the range.

Comment: *Still not working* is neither a valid error code or a valid error description.